# How to retrieve image and text from SQLiteDB to display it in a listview

Tags: android

I need to store data in SQLiteDB and later retrieve it to display it in a ListView in Android. In both SQLiteDB and the ListView, the data will take the form of image and text per row.

Images are stored from sdcard to DB. I have stored my data in the DB; I just don't know how to retrieve the data and display it.

My code:

```
save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        String DishName=edit_dish.getText().toString();
        db.open();
        db.insertImages(DishName, r_photo);
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(ImageDBAct.this,"Data saved",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});

bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //---get all titles---
        db.open();
        Cursor c = db.getAllTitles();
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {          
                String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("dish"));// here dish & image are table field names
                ByteArrayInputStream imageStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(r_photo);
                Bitmap theImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                //l_user_photo.setImageBitmap(theImage);
                //l_user_name.setText(firstName);
                results.add( firstName );
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(ImageDBAct.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
        db.close();
    }
}
```

My DBAdapter is as follows:

```
public class DBAdapter {          
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Dish.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String IMAGES_CREATE =
        "create table images (sno integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "dish text not null, image BLOB, rating integer);";
    private final Context context; 
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(IMAGES_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }   

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    public long insertImages(String uname, byte[] image) {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put("username", uname);
        initialValues.put("image", image);
        return db.insert("images", null, initialValues);
    }

    public Cursor getAllTitles() {
        return db.query("images", new String[] {
            "sno", 
            "dish",
            "image"}, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
    }

    public Cursor getImages(String uname) {
        return db.query("images", new String[] {
            "sno", 
            "image"}, 
            "(username=" +uname+")", 
            null, 
            null, 
            null, 
            null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

More code would have been useful, but from what I can see, you should be using a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html) instead of ArrayAdapter. SimpleCursorAdapter is intended for databases, while ArrayAdapter is more suited to static data that is shipped with your app in the form of, say, string arrays declared in xml.

Also, to get SimpleCursorAdapter to show two views in an item (an ImageView and a TextView in your case) override bindView() and use the provided parameters in that method to create your views.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.Now updated my code above.Detailed help is needed.